# Comparing Columns Not Working Due to Apostrophe

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare two columns on different sheets with the following code:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow22
    For j = 2 To lastRow33
        If ws2.Cells(i, 81) = ws3.Cells(j, 10) Then
            ws2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    Next j
Next I
```

I know that items in the columns match but the loop does not seem to find a match. I further inspected the columns and on one sheet the column cells were all leading with an apostrophe and on the other sheet they were not.

I tried looping through the sheet and removing the apostrophe with the following code and it did not work:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow33
    If ws3.Cells(i, 10) Like "'*" Then
        x = Replace(ws2.Cells(i, 1), "'", "")
        ws3.Cells(i, 10) = x
    End If
Next I
```

Any tips on what I might be able to do to get a match?

Comment: The apostrophe is not part of the contents of the cell - it is simply a marker showing that the cell contains text.  In your original code, you might try `If ws2.Cells(i, 81) = CDbl(ws3.Cells(j, 10)) Then`.

Comment: That gave me a type mismatch :/

Comment: What type of data is in those cells?  Text?  Dates?  Numbers?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to check sorry gimme a minute

Comment: They both return 2 which is text data

Comment: I hovered above and it gave me a warning number stored as text but the other one doesn't give me that warning

Comment: So ill try switch it

Comment: No I don't does the number stored as text raise issues?

Comment: The "number stored as text" should have been fixed by doing the `CDbl(ws3.Cells(j, 10))`, which would have taken the text value and converted it to a double, which could then be compared to true numeric value in `ws2.Cells(i, 81)`.  (Unless some of the values in ws3 are interpretable as numbers and some aren't?  Do you get the "type mismatch" when `j` is 2, or is it further down the column that it crashes?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150128/discussion-between-angatvir-sanghera-and-yowe3k).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at work, and the computers here won't allow me to use chat software.

Comment: If this is a one-off issue, you could write a formula (say in column K) saying `=VALUE(J2)` - that would create a true numeric version of what is currently in J2.  Then copy/paste-values that somewhere, and then copy/paste that back to column J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Cstr` to convert everything to string before comparing. This works for strings as well as numbers so there are no Type Mismatch errors.

Final code:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow22
    For j = 2 To lastRow33
        If Cstr(ws2.Cells(i, 81)) = Cstr(ws3.Cells(j, 10)) Then
            ws2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: I thought this would work but only found three I guess I'll just look back at my columns maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Thanks I believe this would be the fix otherwise.